# Is it possible to compare an ENV variable in the Dockerfile with a regex or similar things like contains?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I'd like to check my VERSION argument, if the regex ".*feature.*" finds the exact string in the version which contains a "feature" in it, to make a conditional docker image.

The dockerfile looks like this right now:

```
FROM docker.INSERTURL.com/fe/plattform-nginx:1.14.0-01
ARG ARTIFACTORY_USER
ARG ARTIFACTORY_PW
ARG VERSION

# Download sources from Repository
ADD https://${ARTIFACTORY_USER}:${ARTIFACTORY_PW}@INSERTURL.com/artifactory/api/npm/angular.npm/angular-frontend-app/-/angular-frontend-app-${VERSION}.tgz app.tar.gz

# Extract and move to nginx html folder
RUN tar -xzf app.tar.gz
RUN mv ./package/dist/angular-frontend-app/* /usr/share/nginx/html

# Start nginx via script, which replaces static urls with environment variables
ADD start.sh /usr/share/nginx/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/start.sh

# Overwrite nginx.conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Fix permissions for runtime
RUN chmod 777 /var/log/nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD /usr/share/nginx/start.sh
```

I'd like it to only download the sources from Artifactory, if the VERSION doesn't contains "feature" in it's name.

I imagine it'd look like this:

```
FROM docker.INSERTURL.com/fe/plattform-nginx:1.14.0-01
ARG ARTIFACTORY_USER
ARG ARTIFACTORY_PW
ARG VERSION

if [ "$VERSION" = ".*feature.*" ]; then
     # Download sources from Repository
     ADD https://${ARTIFACTORY_USER}:${ARTIFACTORY_PW}@INSERTURL.com/artifactory/api/npm/angular.npm/angular-frontend-app/-/angular-frontend-app-${VERSION}.tgz app.tar.gz
fi

# Extract and move to nginx html folder
RUN tar -xzf app.tar.gz
RUN mv ./package/dist/angular-frontend-app/* /usr/share/nginx/html

# Start nginx via script, which replaces static urls with environment variables
ADD start.sh /usr/share/nginx/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/start.sh

# Overwrite nginx.conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Fix permissions for runtime
RUN chmod 777 /var/log/nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD /usr/share/nginx/start.sh
```

Do you know, if it's possible to check Dockerfile ARGs and ENVs with regex?

Comment: Excellent first Q! In the future, realize that the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the problem is sufficient for your Q. But please, keep posting. (Don't know anything about docker). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no conditionals in Dockerfiles.  You can run arbitrary shell code inside a single `RUN` step, but that's as close as you can get.

If your base image has an HTTP client like `curl` you could build a combined command:

```sh
RUN if [ $(expr "$VERSION" : '.*feature.*') -eq 0 ]; then \
     curl -o app.tar.gz https://${ARTIFACTORY_USER}:${ARTIFACTORY_PW}@INSERTURL.com/artifactory/api/npm/angular.npm/angular-frontend-app/-/angular-frontend-app-${VERSION}.tgz \
  && tar -xzf app.tar.gz \
  && mv ./package/dist/angular-frontend-app/* /usr/share/nginx/html \
  && rm -r app.tar.gz package \
; fi
```

(The [`expr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42) invocation tries to match `$VERSION` against that regular expression, and absent any `\(...\)` match groups, returns the number of characters that matched; that is zero if the regexp does not match.)

You can also consider using multiple Dockerfiles for the different variants, or having an intermediate image with this frontend app installed and then dynamically selecting the `FROM` line for your final image.  Also remember that these credentials will be visible in cleartext in the image's `docker history` to anyone who eventually gets the built image.

Comment: I'm late to the thread, but even though the `RUN` step contains shell code with a conditional like this, the `RUN` step stills adds an additional layer to the image, right? I'm not sure about the exact consequences as nothing would be executed, but the additional layer will still increase the image size regardless of whether or not a command in it is being executed. Do you know more about this?

Comment: If the conditional fails, the image will be larger by roughly the size of the `RUN` statement, possibly as many as hundreds of bytes.  The "classic" builder would always create a layer here, BuildKit may or may not, but you're extremely unlikely to notice any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your if + curl in RUN command this should work